# Swagger custom documentation

Tags: java, swagger

Is there a way to generate a README.md file from swagger? I would like to put similar details that would be found in swagger web page plus some custom comments.

Also, is there a way to make a aggregator swagger web page? I want to have the all swagger web pages from all micro services also in a single place. This could enable me to take higher picture notion of my system and maybe do some queries like "how 
many ways certain entity can get this another entity?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding README.md file - not sure what information you want to include in it, but you can write your own method which will do it using [Swagger Parser](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser) in order to get required information from Swagger specification.

Regarding aggregated swagger - you can use [Swagger-aggregate](https://github.com/schroedermatt/swagger-aggregate) for this purpose.